# jquery: open link on doubleclick?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

i wonder if this is the best solution?

```
    $('.folder a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('.folder a').dblclick(function(e) {
    window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

it's working! would you do it in a different manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope that's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing works and is fine technically.

The issue is with the UI. Double-clicking on a hyperlink is not intuitive behaviour. Particularly when disabling the click behaviour. I would suggest a more intuitive UI.

Comment: Looks like he's working with a directory-like view, so you would want to double-click a folder to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a slightly different manner.

```
$('.folder a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).dblclick(function() {
    window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Actually I'd use `.on('click')` and `.on('dblclick')` but in either case they would be chained as above.