# How can you make onclick fires only when clicked twice on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can make this happen only if double clicked on the div

```
  $link='somelink from data base';
    <div onClick="window.location.href='<?php echo $link ;?> ';">xxx</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery: open link on doubleclick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243554/jquery-open-link-on-doubleclick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $link='somelink from data base';
<div ondblclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $link ;?> ';">xxx</div>
```

Comment: Double click is not the same as two clicks

Comment: i mean double click yes

Comment: A doubleclick is two clicks, but indeed 2 seperate clicks is not the same as a single doubleclick... so this was a lucky shot ;)